# React state not updating Framer Motion variant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am trying to simply pass a boolean React state into Framer Motion's variants function. The state doesn't seem to update in the variants. I'm confused. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I can log the state of `beatFast` and it is correct. However the value is not being updated in Framer Motion's variants.

```
import React from "react";
import useMousePosition from "./useMousePosition";

interface HeartIconProps {
  tapped?: boolean;
  x?: MotionValue<number>;
  y?: MotionValue<number>;
}

export function HeartIcon({ tapped, x, y }: HeartIconProps) {
  const [beatFast, setBeatFast] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [beating, setBeating] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!x || !y) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(x?.get(), y?.get());
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    setBeatFast(true);
  }, 3000);

  const heartVariants = (beatFast: boolean) => ({
    resting: {
      scale: [1, 1, 1],
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        repeat: 0,
        duration: 0
      }
    },
    beating: {
      scale: [1, 1.2, 1],
      opacity: 0.9,
      transition: {
        repeat: Infinity,
        duration: beatFast ? 0.4 : 3
      }
    },
    tapped: {
      scale: [3, 1],
      opacity: [0.2, 1],
      transition: {
        type: "spring",
        bounce: 0.5,
        mass: 1
        // times: [0.2, 0.6, 1]
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div ref={svgRef}>
      <motion.svg
        viewBox="0 0 36 36"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="100%"
        animate={tapped ? "tapped" : beating ? "beating" : "resting"}
        variants={heartVariants(beatFast)}
      >
        <path
          d="M35.885 11.833c0-5.45-4.418-9.868-9.867-9.868-3.308 0-6.227 1.633-8.018 4.129-1.791-2.496-4.71-4.129-8.017-4.129-5.45 0-9.868 4.417-9.868 9.868 0 .772.098 1.52.266 2.241C1.751 22.587 11.216 31.568 18 34.034c6.783-2.466 16.249-11.447 17.617-19.959.17-.721.268-1.469.268-2.242z"
          fill={`red`}
        />
      </motion.svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exploding-button-tf2h4c?file=/src/HeartIcon.tsx:0-2068)